# How do I make material like emission but not bloom?

Tags: node-editor, blender-internal-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

Do you have any idea how to make a material node likes emission but

- 1. Doesn't shine or bloom
- 2. It's still has a shadow
- 3. Doesn't catch any shadow on its surface
- 4. Just likes Default material + emission
- 5. IMPORTANT Node for Blender EEVEE

Answer (score 5):

Is this what you're looking for?

[image]

I think *Bloom* is a post-render, whole-frame effect, and some kind of layering would be required to have some objects bloom, and others not, at the same intensity.

---

As an expansion on the above, BSDFs are closures, meaning they're programs waiting to be run later, which can be modified with various node operators but not read from in your material shader. (It helps us stay renderer-agnostic in our materials.) Bloom is a sort of post-processing effect, and involves ray tracing the light from surrounding geometry; but if you're looking for straight-up color and don't care about lighting, just hand it the color (or texture) directly and it will bypass light calculations entirely.

Comment: Thank you @MichaelMacha! Feel free to edit this answer if you can improve it. :)

Comment: Sure, @RobinBetts, I tacked it onto the end. As much as I love closures, they're surprisingly unintuitive for most people.

Comment: @MichaelMacha Hmm!.. it turns out, for me too. My understanding of the use of closures is a bit more hand-wavy than I thought it was.  In particular, if EEVEE implements BSDF as `closure`, how come _Shader to RGB_ is possible in EEVEE, but not in Cycles? I may have to post a Q of my own..

Comment: I actually know the answer to that, too—it deals with the dramatic difference between how Eevee and Cycles work internally. (Very dramatic.) I kind of doubt that my 500-ish characters are going to be enough, so I'll have to wait for your question.

Comment: @MichaelMacha and here's the question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/223902/