# Hypothetical XML representation of shader nodes in Graph editor

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I am playing with a Stud.io (virtual LEGO bricks editor) renderer called Eyesight which is basically a clone of a Blender's Cycles renderer.

It stores its shader nodes and their connections in a xml file. This is a simple example how their represent Emission node from Blender:

```
<emission name="Emission">
   <input name="Color" type="color" value="0.0 0.075 0.0"/>
   <input name="Strength" type="float" value="0.15"/>
</emission>
```

My question is: if someone from you quite experienced Blende r users see this, how would you interpret in this way "Shader to RGB" node?

My own approach - tho it does not work - looks like this:

```
<shader_to_rgb name="ShaderToRGB">
   <input name="Shader" type="closure" />
   <output name="Color" type="color" />
   <output name="Alpha" type="float" />
</shader_to_rgb >
```

What do you think I have wrong there? Any suggestion would be welcomed!

And yes: I already wrote to Stud.io forum this same question tho more specific as it is aimed at their own software directly (Stud.io), but knowing there are no real Stud.io programmers team members who could answer that question only normal users replies, I am also trying my luck here as it is a Blender's Cycles clone, so who knows, right? :-)

Comment: "Shader to RGB" node doesn't work in Cycles. It's an Eevee-only node.

Comment: Oh, that is so bad for me...is there any similar node in Cycles that does what ShaderToRGB does so I can use closure output (green) for color input (yellow)?

Comment: Check out the answers [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/223902/35559) for some explanations of why not, in Cycles.

Comment: I did, thank you. Anyway, I solved this issue in a different way.