# Eevee's "Shader to RGB" equivalent for Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

Is there any sort of way in Cycles to simulate what node "Shader to RGB" does for Eevee?

That is accepting closure (green) input and outputting it as color (yellow)?

BTW I am not using Blender, just a separate renderer called Eyesight which is basically a clone of Cycles renderer, thus what I would like to see is some solution in "one go" made out of nodes that are accepted in Cycles (hoping this does make any sense to you ppl).

Comment: Render the scene once, change your material to look up window coords on your render and use that lookup as your shader->RGB, render the scene again.

Comment: Ehm, what please??? I do not understand at all what are you saying...besides, I am looking for "literal" solution, that is made directly from existing nodes acceptable for Cycles, as I am not using Blender as such, only a renderer based upon its Cycles renderer.

Comment: There isn't a shader equivalent to that in Cycles, mainly because in raytraced renderers like Cycles, each object impacts each other in the scene (while in raster engines like Eevee each of them are basically independent). It's not technically impossible if the devs wanted, but it wouldn't be efficient. You can bake your shader into textures and then redo a shader with these, or edit your shader in compositing.

Comment: More info: [rendering - Why is 'Shader to RGB' possible in EEVEE, but not in Cycles? - Blender Stack Exchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/223902/53447)

Comment: So basically it cannot be done as it would be almost impossible to edit that Eyesight renderer materials all written as a XML file, sad and bad for me, what a pity! :-(

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly do it. Now I don't know What Eyesight allows, but in blender you can render the light in cycles and do the RGB operations you seem to want in the compositor by exporting a whole bunch of Arbitrary output layers to the compositor. If Eyesight has a compositor, you may be able to do something similar or you may find the pipleline you're looking for by switching to blender. Hopefully that was some food for thought.

Comment: thanks for the comment but unfortunately Eyesight is nothing more than GUI-less CMD-like app, basically just a render window where you cannot do anything like that, you just pass parameters to it and it renders your stuff in one go. Anyway I already solved it quite differently by editing Eyesight's XML file containing all the materials shader nodes and their connections - it was quite a challenge but I made it.