Simulate Shader to RGB in Cycles
I currently have a material  working in Eevee, that contains a Shader to RGB and a Color Ramp to achieve shadows and light in my scene. I want to know if I can transfer this to Cycles because I have to export the model.
Here are screenshots of the Eevee and the Cycles views, so it is easier to understand what I mean:









Click image for larger version





Related, with some nice explanatory answers: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/223902/35559

But can it be possible to simulate the effect? I want to export the model but it doesnt have any texture because of it. Do you know a way that i can export my model with textures?

I believe that's a 2-step process, baking out Shader to RGB  results in the tree, wherever they are, and then re-combining. I could be wrong, though.

I really am a noob in blender, so im having a hard time understanding this. What do you mean by baking out shader to RGB results in the tree? bake the different colors one by one?

Yup.. wherever there was a Shader to RGB, bake that branch to  to a texture, and feed it back in. I'm hoping I'm wrong.

but the thing is, to make the texture of that object i just used one shader to RGB. i need to make 3 shaders with 3 different colors? sorry im really new in blender

Can you share a representative file on  https://blend-exchange.com/ ?



I´ve made another version of the texture but to work in Cycles, but either way i cant bake it... It only gives a black image when i try to bake it in diffuse mode, i dont understand what im doing wrong to be honest.
